# Average a list of numbers if greater than 0

Tags: excel

How do I average a list of numbers whose values are greater than 0? I know I can use AVERAGEIF function in Excel

My data is located in A2, A5, A6, A10, A17.

I only want to average it if the data is greater than 0.

Since my data is not an range, I am not able to use AVERAGEIF Function range.

Need some help on this.

**EDIT**

For example,

I tried with three numbers:

```
1) 98.068 and 98.954 and 0 so my forumla looked like this:

=AVERAGE(IF(N(OFFSET(A2,{0,5,10},))>0,N(OFFSET(A2,{0,5,10},))))
```

The answer came out as 99.106. Not sure why.

Comment: You said that you had 5 cells with data. Why does your example only include 3 cells?

Answer (score 2):

A few options:

1)`=SUM(SUMIF(INDIRECT({"A2","A5","A6","A10","A17"}),">0"))/SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"A2","A5","A6","A10","A17"}),">0"))`

2)`=AVERAGE(IF(N(INDIRECT({"A2","A5","A6","A10","A17"}))>0,N(INDIRECT({"A2","A5","A6","A10","A17"}))))`

3)
`=AVERAGE(IF(N(OFFSET(A2,{0,3,4,8,15},))>0,N(OFFSET(A2,{0,3,4,8,15},))))`

2) and 3) must be committed as **array formulas****

Regards

Comment: something wrong with 3. it doesn't give the correct answer. need to check?

Comment: @lakesh are you entering #3 as an Array formula? This means you press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of just ENTER when you confirm the formula.

Comment: @lakesh Can you post the values in those 5 cells, what my formula gives, and what the answer should be?

Comment: @Lakesh You may be averaging the wrong cells, your formula would give the average of cells A2, A7 and A12. I tested it and it was fine.

Answer (score 2):

(0) A simple method

```
=SUM(A2*(A2>0),A5*(A5>0),A6*(A6>0),A10*(A10>0),A17*(A17>0))/SUM(A2>0,A5>0,A6>0,A10>0,A17>0)
```

(4) A more general method

```
=SUM((A1:A20>0)*A1:A20*(ADDRESS(ROW(A1:A20),1,4)={"A2","A5","A6","A10","A17"}))/
SUM((A1:A20>0)*(ADDRESS(ROW(A1:A20),1,4)={"A2","A5","A6","A10","A17"}))
```

The second one is an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

If it's possible to have text in the cells rather than numbers, then this should replace the first formula:-

```
=SUM(N(A2)*(A2>0),N(A5)*(A5>0),N(A6)*(A6>0),N(A10)*(A10>0),N(A17)*(A17>0))/SUM(N(A2)>0,N(A5)>0,N(A6)>0,N(A10)>0,N(A17)>0)
```

(I haven't used N in the > brackets in the numerator because I reason that if A2 etc. is text, the product will always be zero)

I can't persuade N to work with arrays in the second formula, so at the moment I have the rather lengthy

```
=SUM((IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A20),A1:A20,0)>0)*IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A20),A1:A20,0)*(ADDRESS(ROW(A1:A20),1,4)={"A2","A5","A6","A10","A17"}))/
SUM((IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A20),A1:A20,0)>0)*(ADDRESS(ROW(A1:A20),1,4)={"A2","A5","A6","A10","A17"}))
```

but I have tested it on text values and negative numbers and it does seem fine.

The only exception is if one of the cells contains TRUE. In this case the first formula will count it as 1, the second formula will ignore it.

Comment: Thought I should label this as (0) as it's pretty simple-minded.

Comment: What if there are negative numbers within the range?

Comment: I said it was simple-minded! Will see if I can edit it.

Comment: Actually the denominator is good! Much better than my INDIRECT construction. And perhaps the OP doesn't actually have any negative values in the range...

Comment: Nice of you to say so! I have achieved my object of not making the first one an array formula and not making the second one volatile hopefully, but a bit more messy now.

Comment: Thanks. But there was a problem. When A2 has a forumla and there is no value for that cell, it is included in the division as well. How to avoid it?

Comment: It's true, if you compare a string, even the empty string "" to zero it will come out as 'greater than', so if you have these in your cells it will give the wrong answer or a '#VALUE!' error. Think the easiest way to get round it is to use the N function like the excellent XOR LX has done.